# When I click on last progress button & let the progress finish, the slider does not return to the start but disappears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass

I was wondering if anyone can help, I have a codepen:-

https://codepen.io/robbiemcmullen/pen/eoQxKJ

Everything works fine, except when you click on the last button, it does not transition to the start or 1st button & slider like it should do.

My code is as follows, it would be great if anyone can help:-

```
//homepage slider
$(document).ready(function(){

  // set variables length / timeline / items
  // var duration = 5,
    var currentindex = Math.round(Math.random()*(3-1)+1),
    totalitems = $('.info').length,
    timeline = new TimelineMax(),
    item,
    bar,
    duration;

  function runslide() {

      item = $('[data-id='+ currentindex +']');
      bar = item.find('.bar');
      duration = parseInt(item.data('duration'));

      item.addClass('active');

      // if window is more than 768px run timer else pause (this is according to spec)
      if ($(window).width() > 769) {

        timeline.play();
        timeline
          .to(bar, 0, {left: '-100%'})
          .to(bar, duration, {left: '0%', ease: Linear.easeNone, delay: .75, onComplete: function(){
            item.addClass('fadeout');
          }})
          .to(bar, duration/10, {left: '100%', ease: Power4.easeIn, delay: .25, onComplete: function(){
            if(currentindex === totalitems){
              currentindex = 1;
            } else {
              currentindex++;
            }
            item.removeClass('active fadeout');
            timeline.clear();
            runslide();
          }});
      }
  }

  // progress bar and click slide bar
  function clickslide(e) {

    currentindex = e;
    timeline.clear();
    TweenMax.to(bar, duration/10, {left: '0%', ease: Power4.easeOut});
    TweenMax.to(bar, duration/10, {left: '100%', ease: Power4.easeIn, delay: duration/10});

    $('.photo, .info').removeClass('active fadeout');
    runslide();

  }

  $('.slider-banner')
    .on('click', '.info:not(.active, .fadeout)', function(){
      clickslide($(this).attr('data-id'));
      timeline.pause();
    })

    .on('mouseover', '.info.active:not(.fadeout)', function(){
      timeline.pause();
    })
    .on('mouseout', '.info.active:not(.fadeout)', function(){
      timeline.play();
    });


  $('.photo').each(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-image': 'url('+ $(this).attr('data-image') +')'});
  });

  // run on window load
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    runslide();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).attr('data-id')` returns a string and you are setting the currentindex within your `clickslide(e)` function to that value.

After that, you are using the [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) within your `runslide()` function to compare the currentindex, so it jumps to the else condition since `4 !== '4'`.

And within the else condition the `currentindex++;` converts the '4' to 4 and increments it, so the value gets 5 and the currentindex variable keeps incrementing on each `runslide()` call.

Either you use `parseInt()` to parse the string that you get from the data attribute or you use `==` to compare the values.

Comment: Thank you Recep! That's saved me a headache figuring out where I have gone wrong!